# Play audio instantly

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, html5-audio

I've been working on a project where pressing keys on your keyboard will play a sound. I've run into an issue wherein the first press there is a delay of a second or two. After the first press of that key, it works instantly but then if you don't press it for 5 seconds or so and press it again; it reloads and takes that second or two. I don't know if it's possible but I feel like it could be done.

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is - it sounds like it might be a browser loading an asset (sound file) from a server. If that's the case, look into preloading assets. But we really don't have enough information here to know.

Comment: I have a list of files that I am generating <audio> tags when the page loads up. When a key is pressed I am looking for that <audio> and playing the audio. Do you have any links that are useful? I've been looking into that but all I see is `preload=auto`which I already use and hasn't fixed the issue.